# How to programm a clog-log model

Tags: r, statistics

I have programmed a random variable discrete time hazard model in R as the following

```
(logit.full. <-
   glmer(event ~ 
                  + a1
                  + a2
                  + a3
                  + obsnum1 + obsnum2 + obsnum3
                  + (1 + obsnum1 + obsnum2 + obsnum3 | country_cluster),
         family=binomial("logit"), data=data.final))
```

where obsnum 1-3 is the baseline hazard function and a1-a3 are the random effects.

Now I would like to calculate the model with a complementary log-log (clog-log) link, but so far I have not found out, how to specify the link correctly. Does anyone now, how to do this?

Any help would be appreciated very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See ?binomial:
"the 'binomial' family the links 'logit', 'probit', 'cauchit', (corresponding to logistic, normal and Cauchy CDFs respectively) 'log' and 'cloglog' (complementary log-log)"

So you would use:

```
glmer(..., family=binomial("cloglog"), ...)
```